# Laravel Passport Authorization failed

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

After the security improvements of php league oauth2 server, Laravel passport authorization get failed.

Exception says

> You must set the encryption key going forward to improve the security
>   of this library - see this page for more information
>   https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/v5-security-improvements/

According to their documentation it is must to set encryption key.

ie

```
// Setup the authorization server
$server = new AuthorizationServer(
    $clientRepository,
    $accessTokenRepository,
    $scopeRepository,
    $privateKeyPath,
    $publicKeyPath
);
$server->setEncryptionKey('lxZFUEsBCJ2Yb14IF2ygAHI5N4+ZAUXXaSeeJm6+twsUmIen');
```

but Laravel passport current release does not include this fix.

what I did was added setEncryptionKey() manually to

> /vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php

```
public function makeAuthorizationServer()
    {
        $server = new AuthorizationServer(
            $this->app->make(Bridge\ClientRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(Bridge\AccessTokenRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(Bridge\ScopeRepository::class),
            'file://'.Passport::keyPath('oauth-private.key'),
            'file://'.Passport::keyPath('oauth-public.key')
        );
        $server->setEncryptionKey('lxZFUEsBCJ2Yb14IF2ygAHI5N4+ZAUXXaSeeJm6+twsUmIen');
        return $server;
    }
```

This is works for me. But technically I can not edit this file. Is there any suitable fix for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key
sudo chmod 600 storage/oauth-*.key
```

It solves my problem

Comment: Thank you for your response. but this is granting permission. issues is missing setEncryptionKey() method in makeAuthorizationServer(). Passport    maintainers say it has fixed on version v1.0.18 tag. but it is not available in passport v3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did update your laravel passport to

```
"laravel/passport": "^7.0",
```

More details related to security update are here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade